# nginx macro mod like apache?

Tags: nginx, macros

Is there a macro mod for nginx like in apache?

For example, in apache I can do it like:

```
<Macro MyMacro $host $port>
    <VirtualHost $host:$port>
        ServerName $port

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/$host"
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use MyMacro domain1.tld 80
Use MyMacro domain2.tld 80
```